# sfWidgetFormChoice with multiple selections

Tags: php, symfony, select

I'm using symfony 1.4 to make a `CRUD` from a client. This client need to have a select field with multiple choices to generate a newsletter and sent an email. 
I'm setting the s`fWidgetFormChoice` with `multiple => 'true'`, but always i can select just one of items on select. I don't know how to fix this, the googling don't help me. 
Look at my code:

```
$this->widgetSchema['id_news'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('label' => 'News',
    "choices" => $this->getNewsLimitUm(),
    'multiple' => true,
 ));

$this->validatorSchema['id_noticia'] = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false));
```

Comment: why on earth are you using symfony 1.4?

Comment: Try with a List of checkboxes: array('multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with my Id, from select field. I change it and work fine.